# Using Exp development workflow with a pure react-native application

Tags: react-native, expo, development-environment

Might be a duplicate, didn't find one tho.

I started a new application with the **react-native-cli.**

I want to use expo for development purpose:

1. Running on devices through Expo.
2. Publishing through Expo.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 0):

Copy pasting your 2 questions in Google and the first result...

1.
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/testing-on-devices/

2.
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/publishing/

any questions left???

Comment: Maybe I wasn't explaining my self
I know that Expo can publish and let me develop....but can it be done when I'm on not in the expo workflow...I started my app with the react native cli not the expo cli

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible, in the docs its explicitly mentioned you can choose either the expo path or bare react native path. And if you choose expo you can eject from it to pure react native but cant go vice versa because the expo wrapper cant be implemented on the bare app.

so you have to again build an app with expo-cli to use expo publishing facilities etc.
but if you want to use expo modules in bare react native app you can do by using react-native-unimodules .

[rn-unimodules](https://github.com/unimodules/react-native-unimodules)

hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Can you link me to where the docs state that?
I didn't find any documents about this specific.

Comment: i guess you figured it oute. great :D

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is ever looking for the answer it is stated here:

https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/introduction/managed-vs-bare/#bare-workflow

It clearly states that in "bare" workflow you cant use the build services of Expo.